# Metamask, rarible moralis plugin value

Tags: moralis

[image]

Guys, when I use the Rarible plugin from Moralis and perform lazy mint, I'm getting a sign notification from Metamask. May I know what does value mean here?

Answer (score 0):

This sets 100% ownership of this item to the creator address. From the [Rarible documentation](https://docs.rarible.org/reference/mint/?h=10000#lazy-minting-off-chain):

```
creators — value and address of the creator
account — address in Union format ${blockchainGroup}:${token}. For example, 
TEZOS:tz1dKxdpV1hgErMTTKBorb8R5tSz8hFzPhKh
value — value of the part in the ownership of the item. For example, 100% value 
is 10000. If there are several owners, the total cost cannot be more than 10000
```